# codeigniter 404 Page on Item view Page custom issue

Tags: codeigniter

i am new in CI and facing issue with url for 404 page 
http://www.sogoteleshopping.com/product/50/herbal-madhunashni when i access
http://www.sogoteleshopping.com/product/50/herbal-madhunashni_test redirect on same i want 404 here please help me.

$route['product/(:any)'] = "home/product_details/$1";

Comment: in your url hoy have 2 variables **50** and **herbal-madhunashni...** and in your routes.php you only send the first variable `$route['product/(:any)'] = "home/product_details/$1";` you need to replace it for `$route['product/(:num)/(:any)'] = "home/product_details/$1/$2";` and in your controlleryou need to have `function product_details($num, $string){...}`

Comment: Thanks elddenmedio i have  updated according to you getting still same issue now my route $route['product/(:num)/(:any)'] = "home/product_details/$1/$2"; and controller function product_details($num, $string)
 {...}

Comment: what is the answer if you use this `public function product_details($n, $s){echo "from controller var1 -> {$n} | var2 -> {$s}";}`

Comment: http://prntscr.com/fg6iyg
http://prntscr.com/fg6jpl
http://localhost/sogo/product/50/herbal-madhunashni
http://localhost/sogo/product/50/herbal-madhunashni_test
http://prntscr.com/fg6kcg

Comment: it looks that you have an error in your config and .htaccess file, what do you have in in both files? You need to have in your application/config/config.php `$config['base_url'] = "localhost/sogo";` & `$config['index_page'] = '';` and in your root .htaccess `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sogo/index.php/$1 [L]`, are they?

Comment: yes already http://prntscr.com/fg6tb6
http://prntscr.com/fg6th2

Comment: http://prntscr.com/fg6vah

Comment: @vikashkumar yeah its not apache, looks like a routing issue within CI. I sent a few comments in the other post to help troubleshoot. Hard to test without actually seeing your code. But if you're still having issues, I'll be here to help.

Comment: @timothymarois Thanks for supporting but please help me as early as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You have to separate all the segments and use variables for the method `$1/$2/$3` etc

For **your example**, you would need to do:

```
$route['product/(:num)/(:any)'] = "home/product_details/$1/$2";
```

Using `(:num)` for only `[0-9]+` (on your product id segment)

--

Within your `home.php` and method of `product_details()` will use as such:

```
public function product_details($id, $name) {

}
```

> For more information on routing refer to the CI docs:
>
> https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html?highlight=routing

Comment: @vikashkumar is the 404 a CI 404 error or apache 404 error?

Comment: CI 404 when i aceess bad url on itew view page

Comment: @vikashkumar view files can also cause 404 error when not found. You are positive the view file is is correct?

Comment: http://www.sogoteleshopping.com/contact-us
http://www.sogoteleshopping.com/contact-us_test(Getting 404)


@timothymarois
http://www.sogoteleshopping.com/product/50/herbal-madhunashni
http://www.sogoteleshopping.com/product/50/herbal-madhunashni_test(not getting 404 want 404 here also)

Comment: anyother solution Please help me to find out this issue

Comment: @vikashkumar - (unrelated) but, misspelled products in your url on this page http://www.sogoteleshopping.com/pruducts Should this be "products" not "pruducts"

Comment: @vikashkumar on the `product_details()` function can you remove "everything" in there, and just do `die("test");` if that works than its hitting the method. If not, than it's due to routing.

Comment: @vikashkumar can you show me the actual code you're using in product details function. Looks like it's not routing.

Comment: function product_details()
 {
  $this->load->model('homes');
  $args=func_get_args();
  $data['METATAG']= $this->homes->selectProductById($args[0]); //$this->tags->selecttagbyid(3); //meta tag
  $data['PRODUCTDATA']= $this->homes->selectAllActiveProduct();

  $data['PRODUCT']= $this->homes->selectProductById($args[0]);

Comment: how can i send you its too long code validation error on stackoverflow

Comment: @vikashkumar maybe just take a snapshot of the code. Or update the original question with the code, the comments won't fit all that.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/fh8to6    http://prntscr.com/fh8tsv here is the print screen of code

Comment: @vikashkumar can you confirm that `front/product_details` view file exists? Because that would cause a 404 if not found.